# is a ring with 2 elements must be ring with unity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

question: If A is a ring with exactly two elements, must it be a ring with unity?

this is what i found. it doesn't have to be ring with unity coz the ring it self is closed under the multiplication operation (without the need to include the unity).

Comment: Take the group $\Bbb Z/2$ and define $a \cdot b = 0$ for all $a$, $b$. What do you get?

Comment: thats 0 and 1. thanks. but what if it's a group of two matrices. does it have to be unity?

Comment: Just to be clear, $1$ will not be the identity in my earlier example. For your other question, think about $\left\{\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0
\end{smallmatrix}\right),\,\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0
\end{smallmatrix}\right)\right\}$.

Comment: ohh, I see. so there must be a unity there (i.e. 0 in the previous example and not one) so that it can be closed under multiplication.

Comment: "coz" is SMS style.  To be avoided when asking a question here.

Comment: @ien: No, neither $0$ nor $1$ is an identity. There is no identity because $1 \cdot a \neq 1$ for all $a$.